# javascript count number of textboxes with an "X" in them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having issues counting the number of X's entered into a bunch of individual textboxes (25 of them). my textboxes are all structured as follows:

```
<td>
   <input class="jq-hitOrMiss" onchange="SumHits();"  pattern="[xXoO]" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1"  />
</td>
```

and the jquery I am using to try to count them:

```
function SumHits() {
        var sum = 0;
        var inputs = $('.jq-hitOrMiss');
        $.each( inputs , function( index, value ){
            var value = $(value).val;
            if(value == 'X' || value == 'x'){
                sum++
            }
        });
        alert(sum + " " + inputs.length);
        var totalInput = $('.jq-total');
        totalInput.text = sum;
    }
```

the alert I put pop up has the values 0 and 25 in them. Many of these boxes have X's in them so I know the 0 is incorrect ad the 25 seems correct as there is 25 textboxes. All help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.val` needs to be `.val()`, to call the method. Otherwise you are trying to access a `val` property on the jQuery object.

```
var value = $(value).val();
//                      ^^
```

---

Another way of doing the count is to use `filter()`

```
var sum = $('.jq-hitOrMiss').filter(function(){
    return this.value.toUpperCase() == 'X';
}).length;
```